# Symfony : Form : get Key Children

Tags: symfony

How can I get children → elements key?
(see screenshot, I want to access and modify  0, 3, 2)

I need this for add error on collection form.

Thank you!

[image]

[EDIT]

```
foreach ($form->getData()->getCategs() as $d) {                  
     if ($d->getNbHeures() > 8){
         $form->get('categs')->get($nb)->get('nbHeures')->addError(new FormError('Vous ne pouvez pas saisir plus de 8h.'));
         $nbErreur++;
      }
}
```

I need to get `$nb`.

[EDIT]
I founded this, but I don't know if it's the best solution:

```
foreach ($form->get('categs') as $k => $d) {
    if ($d->getData()->getNbHeures() > 8) {
        $form->get('categs')->get($k)->get('nbHeures')->addError(new FormError('Vous ne pouvez pas saisir plus de 8h.'));
        $nbErreur++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the code you have tries

Comment: Ok, this is work, but i dont know if its best : foreach($form->get('categs') as $k=>$d){

                        if($d->getData()->getNbHeures()>8){
                            $form->get('categs')->get($k)->get('nbHeures')->addError(new FormError('Vous ne pouvez pas saisir plus de 8h.'));
                            $nbErreur++;
                        }
                    }